# Decodificar QRCode

Tags: python, qrcode, iot

Estou estudando um pouco de *IoT* e estou tentando criar um "abridor de porta" por *QRCode*(quando alguém mostrar um QRCode para camera, ele vai identificar e abrir a porta)

Porém a camera que possuo em casa é uma **Logitech C270**(3MP e sem Foco Automático), o código eu consegui fazer usando o `PyGame.camera`, porém a imagem fica muito estranha. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

O problema está no código ou na câmera?

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
SAVEDIR = "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/Qr/"

import pygame, sys
import pygame.camera
import time, random

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (1280,960))


print ("Taking a shot:")
cam.start()
image = cam.get_image()
cam.stop()

timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S", time.localtime())
filename = "%s/%s.jpg" % (SAVEDIR, timestamp)
print ("saving into %s" % filename)

pygame.image.save(image, filename)
`
```

OBS: O *QRCode* tem 1cm de altura por 1,5cm de largura.

Comment: A qualidade de imagem está muito ruim, não é possível realizar a leitura pois está muito desfocado.

Comment: Você precisa fazer o foco manual, girando a lente na ponta da câmera de acordo com a distância

Comment: Infelizmente a camera não possui o foco =/ Estou desesperado ja